# Codeigniter Active Record Update - Error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to do a simple update where I pass an array from the Controller to the Model.  But I am getting the following error:

```
Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'id #29
```

Here is the array that is being passed:

```
<?
 $data = Array
  (
   [name] => last_name
   [value] => Smith
   [pk] => 611
  );
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 <?
 function edit_client() {
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $this->load->model('clients_model');
    $this->clients_model->update_client_info($data);
 }
```

**MODEL**

```
 <?
 function update_client_info($data) {
    $update = $this->db->set($data['name'], $data['value']);
    $this->db->where('id', $data['pk']);
    $this->db->update('clients', $update); 
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `$this->db->set()` function.

Do the following

```
$this->db->set('name',$data['name']);
$this->db->set('value',$data['value']);
$this->db->where('id', $data['pk']);
$this->db->update('clients');
```

That should do the trick. 
When you use the `$this->db->set()` , you need not pass anything other than the table name to the insert or update functions.